# Incorrectly calculates 100% width when parent width is an odd pixel value - Bootstrap (Chrome)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap design my web. But i get an error :

Bootstrap not calculates exactly width, when parent width is an odd pixel value, as:

```
<div class="row"> => *1251 pixel*
  <div class="col-xs-6"></div> => 555.5 pixel
    <table class="table">...</table> => 545.5 pixel
  <div class="col-xs-6"></div> => 555.5 pixel
</div>
```

In here , My table not full width : [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjGd5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to put your table inside your column of class col-xs-6 if you want it to take half the width of the row.

Then, remove padding and margin from the column otherwise it will be bigger than its children. 
1251/2 = 625.5, (625.5-555.5)/2 = 35, it probably has a padding of 15 px and a margin of 20 px on each sides. Put both to 0 and you will have no problem.